# Schauder fixed point theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I am teaching a course in functional analysis and I would like to illustrate the Schauder fixed point theorem (just for Banach spaces) with some nice applications. One that comes to  my mind is the existence of solutions of ordinary differential equations. Applications to nonlinear PDEs would require too much knowledge.

> **Question** What are the elementary and nice applications of the Schauder fixed point theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Chapter 3 of the [Methods in Nonlinear Integral Equations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-015-9986-3)

I am not an expert on integral equations but the authors uses Schauder's theorem to prove existence theorems for continuous solutions of the integral equation associated with the Fredholm integral operator, the Volterra integral operator, and in particular integral operator with delay.

Obviously you are right about the most elementary application which comes to mind. Peano's existence theorem for ODE in Jake Hale's ODE book on page 15 is proved by Schauder's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. The Schauder fixed point theorem is the Brouwer fixed point theorem adapted to topological vector spaces, so it's difficult to find elementary applications that require Schauder specifically. Any problem requiring the full power of this theorem will be infinite-dimensional, so if the solution theory for differential equations or variational inequalities is excluded as too advanced there isn't much left. Could you use the many [illustrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#Illustrations) of Brouwer's theorem instead, as a special case? The linked Wikipedia article also indicates there are lots of other theorems which have at bottom the same idea (the no-retract theorem + some compactness notion) many of which are actually equivalent to Brouwer's theorem, and which also have strikingly concrete consequences in physics and economics.
2. From a functional analysis/PDE perspective the main heuristic takeaway from Schauder is that apriori estimates imply existence. If you don't wish to give the full Leray-Schauder story you could just cook up a simple functional or integral equation, have the students make an estimate then appeal to Schauder for the existence of a solution.